# Python import error: Symbol not found, but the symbol <s>is</s> *is not* present in the file

Tags: python, macos

I get this error when I try to import `ssrc.spread`:

`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssrc/_spread.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE`

The file in question (`_spread.so`) includes the symbol:

```
$ nm _spread.so | grep _ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
     U __ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
     U __ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
```

(twice because the file is a fat ppc/x86 binary)

EDIT:

okay, as James points out, the U means that the symbol is *undefined* but required by the object file.

With some more digging I've noticed (where I should have looked first...) these linker errors during compilation:

```
CC=g++ CXX=g++ g++-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -O3 -I../.. -I../.. -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -O2 -I/usr/local/include -std=c++98 -pipe -fno-gnu-keywords -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -o SsrcSpread.o -c SsrcSpread.cc
CC=g++ CXX=g++ /bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python \
  -pthread -D_REENTRANT -pedantic -Wall -Wno-long-long -Winline -Woverloaded-virtual -Wold-style-cast -Wsign-promo -L../../ssrc -lssrcspread -L/usr/local/lib -ltspread-core  -o _spread.so SsrcSpread.o
mkdir .libs
g++-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -pthread -D_REENTRANT -pedantic -Wall -Wno-long-long -Winline -Woverloaded-virtual -Wold-style-cast -Wsign-promo -o _spread.so SsrcSpread.o -Wl,-bind_at_load  -L/Dev/libssrcspread-1.0.6/ssrc /Dev/libssrcspread-1.0.6/ssrc/.libs/libssrcspread.a -L/usr/local/lib -ltspread-core  
ld: warning: in ~/Dev/libssrcspread-1.0.6/ssrc/.libs/libssrcspread.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (ppc)
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/local/lib/libtspread-core.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (ppc)
ld: warning: in /Dev/libssrcspread-1.0.6/ssrc/.libs/libssrcspread.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/local/lib/libtspread-core.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

I'm also not entirely sure that the 10.4 sdk is the right one for compiling python modules (but switching to 10.6 didn't seem to help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ nm _spread.so | grep _ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
     U __ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
     U __ZN17ssrcspread_v1_0_67Mailbox11ZeroTimeoutE
```

The _spread.so file does not include the symbol, it is depending on it. The `U` means undefined.

I feel like there may be a version mismatch somewhere, perhaps between the headers and the library binaries. Do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: Ah, thanks!

Yes, well, I have multiple versions of python (but all the files in /usr/bin are for one version, and the compilation seems to be piking up the right one), and have previously had different versions of ssrcspread and spread --- but the current version is replacing the old ones.

I've also noticed some linker warning messages that might be the root of the problem, see above.