# MacOSX + Boost_Python + PyFTGL :- Symbol not found, expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python, macos, importerror, boost-python, ftgl

I am trying to install PyFTGL on MacOSX Yosemite.

The python version I am using is 2.7 from macports. I have installed boost from macports specifying +python27.

To install PyFTGL I built from source and edited the setup.py file from:

```
module_ftgl_libs = [
    'GLU',
    'GL',
    'freetype',
    'z',
    'ftgl',
    'boost_python',
    ]

 module_ftgl = Extension(
    'FTGL',
    module_ftgl_src,
    include_dirs=module_ftgl_include_dirs,
    libraries=module_ftgl_libs
    )
```

to:

```
 module_ftgl_libs = [
    'freetype',
    'z',
    'ftgl',
    'boost_python',
    ]

 module_ftgl = Extension(
    'FTGL',
    module_ftgl_src,
    include_dirs=module_ftgl_include_dirs,
    libraries=module_ftgl_libs,
    extra_link_args=['-framework', 'OpenGL', '-framework', 'GLUT']
    )
```

I then build the setup.py file and copy the resulting FTGL.so file to the same folder as my python code test.py which uses the FTGL functions.

My problem is when I now run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    import FTGL
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/james/Desktop/test/FTGL.so, 2): Symbol not found:__ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionERKNSt3__14pairIPNS0_6detail7keywordESA_EE
  Referenced from: /Users/james/Desktop/test/FTGL.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/james/Desktop/test/FTGL.so
```

I don't know much about linking, setup.py files and boost and I have spent a long time researching on both Google and Stack Overflow but now I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Can you try using nm to display your symbol table in FTGL.so?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989233/python-import-error-symbol-not-found-but-the-symbol-sis-s-is-not-present

Answer (score 2):

Using `c++filt`, the symbol can be decoded as:

```cpp
$ c++filt -n _ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionERKSt4pairIPKNS0_6detail7keywordES9_E
boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)
```

Since I have the same issue, I looked for similar symbols in the libboost_python.dylib:

```cpp
$ nm -gU ~/Downloads/boost_1_60_0/bin.v2/libs/python/build/darwin-4.2.1/debug/libboost_python.dylib | grep function_object
0000000000027cd0 T __ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionE
0000000000027c20 T __ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionERKNSt3__14pairIPKNS0_6detail7keywordESA_EE
```

One of which decodes as:

```cpp
boost::python::objects::function_object(boost::python::objects::py_function const&, std::__1::pair<boost::python::detail::keyword const*, boost::python::detail::keyword const*> const&)
```

The only difference is that the boost dynamic lib uses `std::__1::pair` instead of `std::pair`.

As also mentioned here: [Why can't clang with libc++ in c++0x mode link this boost::program_options example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp), `libc++` and `libstdc++` are not compatible.  One option is to recompile boost with `libstdc++`:

```cpp
./b2 cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" python
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this error by uninstalling all boost libraries then using `brew install boost155 --with-python --with-mpi --without-single` and switching from homebrew gcc/g++-5 to gcc/g++-4.9

go to `brew edit boost155` and replace the layout from `tagged` to `system` if possible