# What does "Symbol not found / Expected in: flat namespace" actually mean?

Tags: python, c++, import, namespaces, importerror

When I import a module I built, I get this boost-python related error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(./myMod.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionERKSt4pairIPKNS0_6detail7keywordES9_E
  Referenced from: ./myMod.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./myMod.so
```

What does this actually mean? Why was this error raised?

Comment: It means the symbol wasn't found. Where was the symbol supposed to be?

Comment: @immibis I think that gcc expected gcc code and it found clang code instead, and that the compiler is reporting not having found the gcc symbol

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Barry This is a broad error message, which could apply to several situations. Over 1000 people viewed this before I added the bounty. The intent of this question is not to solve my specific problem (I solved this. It was caused by compiling a library with clang and running it with gcc.) I expect many people to find this message in many contexts. The goal of this question is to seek an understanding about the general meaning of this error message.

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777337/macosx-boost-python-pyftgl-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### Description

The problem was caused by mixing objects that compiled with *`libc++`* and object that compiled with *`libstdc++`*.

In our case, the library `myMod.so` (compiled with *`libstdc++`*) need `boost-python` that compiled with *`libstdc++`* (`boost-python-libstdc++` from now). When `boost-python` is `boost-python-libstdc++`, it will work fine. Otherwise - on computer that its `boost-python` has compiled with *`libc++`* (or another c++ library), it will have a problem loading and running it.

In our case, it happens because that *`libc++`* developers intentionally changed the name of all of their symbols to prevent you (and save you) from mixing code from their library and code from a different one: `myMod.so` need a function that take an argument from the type. In `libc++`, this type's name is `std::__1::pair`. Therefore, this symbol was not found.

To understand why mixing two version of the same API is bad, consider this situation: There are two libraries: `Foo` and `Bar`. They both have a function that takes a `std::string` and uses it for something but they use a different c++ library. When a `std::string` that has been created by `Foo` will be passed to `Bar`, `Bar` will think that this is an instance of its c++ library's `std::string` and then bad things can happen (they are a completely different objects).

**Note**: In some cases, there would be no problem with two or more different versions of the same API in a completely different parts of a program. There will be a problem if they will pass this API's objects between them. However, checking that can be very hard, especially if they pass the API object only as a member of another object. Also, a library's initialization function can do things that should not happen twice. Another version may do these things again.

#### How to solve that?

- You can always recompile your libraries and make them match each other.
- You can link `boost-python` to your library as a static library. Then, it will work on almost every computer (even one that doesn't has `boost-python` installed). See more about that [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/choosing_a_boost_python_library_.html#ftn.building.choosing_a_boost_python_library_.the_dynamic_binary.f0).

#### Summary

`myMod.so` need another version of `boost-python`, one that compiled with a specific c++ library. Therefore, It would not work with any another version.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was receiving:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_xmlSecDSigNs'
```

**BACKGROUND:**

M1 MacBook Pro with Montery

I was working with a python virtualenv (using pyenv) to use an earlier version of python3.8 (3.8.2), while my system had 3.8.10 installed natively.

While I was in the activated 3.8.2 virtualenv I noticed the path in dlopen() was pointing to the package in the native python install NOT the virtualenv install.

**SOLUTION:**

In my case, I did not need the native 3.8 version at all so I simply removed it and this solved the problem.

Comment: Removing and recreating the venv worked for me

Answer (score 7):

One of the solutions I found was to uninstall and reinstall it using the no-binary flag, which forces pip to compile the module from source instead of installing from precompiled wheel.

```
pip install --no-binary :all: <name-of-module>
```

Found this solution [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1124#issuecomment-1318793968)

Comment: I think this actually worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I encounter the same problem.

```
Expected in: flat namespace
```

Add the linker flag fixes the problem

```
-lboost_python37
```

change the dynamic library name to the one installed on the os.

By the way, my os is macOS High Sierra and I use brew to install `boost_python3`.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with pyenv compiled pythons on Mojave and I really want to make pyenv to work instead of having to deal with py version manangement in a different way. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1242 -- Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: it is boost-python3 not boost_python3

Comment: Can you describe how the linker flag should be added?

Answer (score 3):

Symbol not found means the definition of the declared function or variable was not found. When a header file of a shared object is compiled with your program, linker adds symbols of declared functions and objects to your compiled program. When your program is loaded by the OS's loader, the symbols are resolved so that their definition will be loaded. It is only at this time where if the implementation is missing, loader complains it couldn't find the definition due to may be failing to resolve the actual path to the library or the library itself wasn't compiled with the implementation/source file where the definition of the function or object resides. There is a good article on this on the linux journal http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6463.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was just failing to import all the required sources (c++ files) when compiling with Cython.

From the string after "Symbol not found" you can understand which library you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've learned (osx):

If this is supposed to work (i.e. it works on another computer), you may be experiencing clang/gcc issues. To debug this, use `otool -l` on the .so file which is raising the error, or a suspect library (in my example it's a boost-python dylib file) and examine the contents. Anything in the /System/ folder is built with clang, and should be installed somewhere else with the gcc compiler. Never delete anything in the /System folder.

Answer (score 1):

`.so` files are dynamic libraries (so = shared object). On Windows they are called `.dll` (dynamic-link library). They contain compiled code which contains functions available for usage to any executable which links them.

What is important to notice here is that those `.so` are not Python files. They were probably compiled from C or C++ code and contain public functions which can be used from Python code (see documentation on [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)).

On your case, well, you have a corrupt `.so`. Try reinstalling the affected libraries, or Python, or both.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

I had this same issue when running puma as part of Rails app

> LoadError:
> dlopen(/Users/alucard/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ERR_load_crypto_strings'
>
> - /Users/alucard/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle

#### Solution

It was solved just by installing puma gem again `gem install puma`