# Can't run tensorboard because of " Symbol not found: _PyBytes_AsString"

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5, tensorboard

I've been trying to run tensoarboard without any success. I can see that the function **tf.summary.FileWriter()** is working since I can see that the logFile is created in the right folder. But when I run in my terminal:

```
    tensorboard --logdir=/private/tmp/mnist/2 --port=6006
```

I get :

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):**
**File**"/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 32, in <module>
**from** tensorflow.python.summary import event_file_inspector as efi
**File** "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/summary/event_file_inspector.py", line 122, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
**File** "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py", line 22, in <module>
**from** tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io import copy as Copy
  **File** "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 27, in <module>
**from** tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  **File** "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
**File** "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
**ImportError**: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBytes_AsString
**Referenced from**: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
**Expected in**: flat namespace
in /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
```

I don't know how to deal with the **Symbol not found: _PyBytes_AsString** and **Expected in: flat namespace**. There is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean) that talks about a similar error I think but it didn't help me.

The code I used can be found on this [tutorial](http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/04/how-to-use-tensorboard/) and I'm on MacOS Sierra 10.12.1

Comment: Did you already manage to fix it? I have the same problem on MacOS 10.12.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem just like yours. In my case, I installed python, python3 packages via Homebrew on OS X 10.11.6, and I executed my project on python3.
In my opinion, the symptom of “Symbol not found” problem might be caused by that our tensorboard linked to the wrong python frameworks.
I found this issue opened at Homebrew/legacy-homebrew ‘[python3 framework installation incomplete? #20591](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/20591)’.
Like *samueljohn* said that ‘the Frameworks are not correctly linked into homebrew's prefix.’
So, I just followed his guidance, and created the link on my own.

```
brew update
brew unlink python python3
brew link python
brew link python3
```

Please excuse my limited English ability, but hope this helps.