# conda: importing pandas package produces error on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I'm new to conda, but I'm sure I have pandas installed in the base environment. I also have selected it as the python interpreter in VSCode. However, when I try to import pandas it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/Documents/UNIDOCS/Python:Psychopy:RALT/Rando/Randomization.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly  # noqa:F401
  File "/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/raimundbuehler/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/interval.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 1800
```

I'm assuming numpy to be the problem, but updating both numpy and pandas didn't solve it. It may also be because I have Pycharm and pip installed, so it may be messy regarding multiple installations of python and packages... in fact in Pycharm, I can import pandas (using a different interpreter). Any help how to find out if this is indeed the case and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can it run if you install package by using `conda install pandas` command?

Comment: Yes, im getting ```# All requested packages already installed.```

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761175/how-to-solve-importerror-dlopen-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-name).

I think the feasible way may still be to unload and reinstall.