# Pytorch stateful lstm symbol not found

Tags: python, torch

I am getting the following error when importing StatefulUnidirectionalLSTM from pytorch_stateful_lstm :

```
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytorch_stateful_lstm/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _pytorch_stateful_lstm import (
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytorch_stateful_lstm.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN3c1019UndefinedTensorImpl10_singletonE
  Referenced from: /Users/user/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytorch_stateful_lstm.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/user/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytorch_stateful_lstm.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

My environment information is:

```
Is debug build: No
CUDA used to build PyTorch: None

OS: Mac OSX 10.14.6
GCC version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect

Python version: 3.7
Is CUDA available: No
CUDA runtime version: No CUDA
GPU models and configuration: No CUDA
Nvidia driver version: No CUDA
cuDNN version: No CUDA

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.18.2
[pip3] pytorch-fast-elmo==0.6.12
[pip3] pytorch-stateful-lstm==1.6.0
[pip3] torch==1.0.1.post2
[conda] Could not collect
```

Has any one encountered this error and how to fix it?

Comment: when do you get the error? while installing or importing? Also, post the full error message with the code that may be causing this.

Comment: updated with full error message. The error arises when importing.

Comment: some version mismatch, maybe you need to recompile. Check if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean

Comment: thanks. I tried but get the same error.