# CMake: can't use gtest built from source with error " 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found"

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I was trying to build GTest from source and then link my target to it using cmake. But I see this error

```
mygtest % cmake --build build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello_test.dir/mytest.cpp.o
/path/to/test/mygtest/mytest.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_test.dir/mytest.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My question is what may I miss here?

This is my CMakeList File

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_library(
  GTEST_MAIN
  gtest_main
  PATHS /path/to/googletest/build/lib/
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  )

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  mytest.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  ${GTEST_MAIN}
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

What did I try?

1. Printing the target's link libraries

```
get_target_property(HELLO_TEST_LIBRARIES hello_test LINK_LIBRARIES)
include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(HELLO_TEST_LIBRARIES)

// OUTPUT
-- HELLO_TEST_LIBRARIES="/path/to/googletest/build/lib/libgtest_main.a"
```

2. using find_package(GTest) and then linking GTest::gtest works, but I don't want to use a precompiled version -- it seems to cause the error "Unfound Symbol" as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean)

Comment: Don't use `find_library`... use `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` and then link to `GTest::gtest` and `GTest::gtest_main`.

Comment: @Yinglao Liu, your CMakeLists is already written so that you expect a precompiled gtest (due to `find_library()`), but you miss injection of headers folder, and it's just old & fragile CMake style. So follow @Alex Reinking advice, and use `find_package()` & link to imported targets like a good citizen: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html

Answer (score 0):

I am open to any other better answers, but would post my current solution for those who might be interested.

Thanks @Alex Reinking and @SpacePotatoes for comments. based on what's suggested, inserting the following piece of codes to your CMakeLists.txt would allow you to automate the process of downloading googletest and building from source.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
 googletest
 GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
 GIT_TAG           main
 SUBBUILD_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-subbuild
 BINARY_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build
 SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src
 )

FetchContent_Populate(
  googletest
)

execute_process(COMMAND cmake -S. -B${googletest_BINARY_DIR} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${googletest_SOURCE_DIR})
execute_process(COMMAND cmake --build . WORKING_DIRECTORY ${googletest_BINARY_DIR})

set(GTEST_LIBRARY ${googletest_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libgtest.a)
set(GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ${googletest_SOURCE_DIR}/googletest/include)
set(GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY ${googletest_BINARY_DIR}/lib/libgtest_main.a)

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
```

Then you might be able to link to your target with

```
target_link_libraries(<target> GTest::gtest_main)
```