# Symbol not found using dlopen in Python

Tags: python, shared-libraries, bitcoin, dylib, dlopen

I [compiled BlockSci](https://citp.github.io/BlockSci/setup.html#mac-os-10-15) in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. This created `/usr/local/lib/libblocksci.dylib`. I used `pip3` to install the `blocksci` Python analysis library and this created `/Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy/blocksci/_blocksci.cpython-39-darwin.so`.

When I try to import the library via `$ python3 hello.py`:

```
import blocksci
```

It creates the following error in `dlopen` due to a symbol not found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import blocksci
  File "/Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy/blocksci/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._blocksci import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy/blocksci/_blocksci.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN8blocksci10heuristics16getPoisonTaintedERSt6vectorINS_6OutputESaIS2_EEib
  Referenced from: /Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy/blocksci/_blocksci.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy/blocksci/_blocksci.cpython-39-darwin.so
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-macos#:%7E:text=so%20on%20mac%20os%20x,you%20use%20%2Dshared%20and%20for%20.) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean) to be informative but I can't determine how to fix this so I can interact with the C++ library.

Finally, `pip3 list` returns:

```
Package               Version     Editable project location
--------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------
astroid               2.5
blocksci              0.7.0       /Users/${USER}/dev/BlockSci/blockscipy
certifi               2021.10.8
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was mixing compilers, using clang for the BlockSci code and gcc in pybind11 to bind the C++ code with Python.