# dyld[23882]: symbol not found in flat namespace (_cblas_caxpy)

Tags: cblas

I am trying to execute a python code on MacOs put I am getting the symbol not found in flat namespace error. My friend using a linux OS has been able to compile the same code using the same command I used. Please how do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Symbol not found / Expected in: flat namespace" actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006614/what-does-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace-actually-mean)